# Is there a way to use group by together with a total sum of values in group by?

Tags: sql

Very new to SQL and hopefully someone can help me with following concept:

```
SELECT name, sum(amount) as balance
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

If the 'Name' variable contain A, B and C I will of course by the above statement get the balance per A, B and C.

However if want the total balance of all 'Names' I can remove the Group by clause and 'Name' from SELECT but my question is if this can be solved in one script? Basically, can I in some way add a row under 'Name' called Total which gives tha balance of A, B and C. So result should contain A, B, C and Total under 'Name' with respective balance?

Thanks,

Comment: Look into grouping sets?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, sum(amount) as balance
FROM table
GROUP BY name

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', sum(amount) as balance
FROM table
```

This might be able to help you out

Comment: Number of columns don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support this functionality as a `GROUP BY` modifier.  The standard functionality uses `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT name, sum(amount) as balance
FROM table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (name), () );
```

In this example (with one key), you can also use `ROLLUP`.  The exact syntax varies by database.